# Load Telegram account on page HTML with iframe tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can I see the personal account of the Telegram in the iframe tag?

I tried the following code but it does not work:

```
<iframe src="https://telegram.me/joinchat/BfNEij9CbDh03kwXacO5OA"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Telegram does not allow you to show their webpage in an iframe. You can see the message when you view the console:

[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

This is, because the Site explicitly refuses it using `X-Frame-Options` header set to `sameorigin`. You'd probably need to use the [telegram-api](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api). There is a [JavaScript Library](https://github.com/sunriselink/TelegramApi) for that but it's a bit more advanced then just showing an IFrame. It will take you some time, you need to authenticate against the App etc.

Comment: how use j.s library? please help me tanks.